# a variant of Fitch's algorithm when it is known that one path has cost 0?

Tags: algorithms, trees, bioinformatics

[Fitch's algorithm](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Courses/CPSC536A-01/Class10/class10-notes.html) solves the small parsimony problem - given tree topology and leaf labels, but not internal node labels, find best internal node labels (i.e. best score) for that tree. The score is the number of edges $u->v$ with different labels $L_u \neq L_v$.

I need a variant on Fitch's algorithm when it is known that there is one path from root to some leaf with cost 0.

Comment: Fitch will give you a set of labels for each node. If your assumption is right there must be a leaf with label such that all nodes on the path from the leaf to the root carry that label. Can't you just find such a label and assign that to the root?